Kernel Not Loading Properly at 1MB in Bootloader – Showing Empty Memory in QEMU
I am working on building a simple bootloader that loads a kernel from disk into memory at the 1MB mark (0x100000). The bootloader consists of two stages: Stage 1 reads the second stage, and Stage 2 loads the kernel from the disk into memory.
I am testing this with QEMU and checking the memory contents using the QEMU monitor. However, after loading the kernel, the memory at 0x100000 shows all zeros (empty), meaning that the kernel isn't being loaded into memory as expected.
I am using NASM for the bootloader, GCC for compiling the kernel in C, and QEMU for emulation. I've also checked my linker script to ensure the kernel is linked to start at 0x100000. Additionally, I am using Docker to build everything.
stage1.asm:
[BITS 16]               ; We are working in 16-bit Real Mode
[org 0x7c00]            ; The origin (starting address) of the bootloader in memory, which is 0x7C00 as loaded by the BIOS.
                        ; This is the physical address where the bootloader is loaded into memory.
start:                  ; Start of execution, this label marks the entry point of the code.
    jmp 0x0000:main            ; Jump to the 'main' label to start execution.

main:                   ; Main routine of the bootloader begins here.

; -------------------------
; Setup segment registers
; -------------------------
    cld                 ; Set direction forward (DF=0) for string instructions (STOS, LODS, CMPS etc)
    cli                 ; Clear interrupts to ensure no interrupts occur while setting up segments.
    xor ax, ax          ; Set AX to 0x0 (which is 0x0 >> 4).
                        ; Explanation: We are using segment:offset addressing in real mode.
                        ; Physical address = Segment * 16 + Offset
                        ; So, the segment 0x0 * 16 = 0x0 (physical address).
    mov ds, ax          ; Set Data Segment (DS) to 0x0. DS points to the bootloader code/data in memory.
    mov es, ax          ; Set Extra Segment (ES) to 0x0. ES is also set to point to our code/data.

; -------------------------
; Setup stack
; -------------------------
    mov ss, ax          ; Set Stack Segment (SS) to 0 (base of memory).
    mov sp, 0xFFFE      ; Set the Stack Pointer (SP) to the highest address within the current 64KB segment (0x0000:0xFFFE).
                        ; In real mode, the stack grows downward from 0xFFFE and 0xFFFE should be set to an even offset like 0xFFFE, not an odd one.

    sti                 ; Re-enable interrupts after segment and stack setup is complete.

; -------------------------
; Load Stage 2 bootloader from disk
; -------------------------
    mov ah, 02h         ; BIOS Interrupt 13h, Function 02h: Read sectors from the disk.
    mov al, 01h         ; Read 1 sector from the disk (this corresponds to the size of a sector, which is 512 bytes).

    mov ch, 00h         ; Set Cylinder number to 0 (since both Stage 1 and Stage 2 are on Cylinder 0).
    mov cl, 02h         ; Set Sector number to 2 (Stage 1 is in Sector 1, so Stage 2 starts at Sector 2).
    mov dh, 00h         ; Set Head number to 0 (assuming we are using Head 0 for now).
    mov dl, 80h         ; Use the first hard drive (usually 0x80 for the primary hard disk).

    mov bx, 0x8000      ; Set BX to 0x8000, the offset address where Stage 2 will be loaded.
                        ; Stage 2 will be loaded into memory using segment:offset addressing.
                        ; ES = 0x0, BX = 0x8000, so the physical address = ES * 16 + BX.
                        ; Formula: 0x0 * 16 + 0x8000 = 0x0 + 0x8000 = 0x8000 (the physical address where Stage 2 is loaded).

    int 13h             ; Call BIOS interrupt 13h to read the specified sectors into memory.

    jc disk_read_error  ; If carry flag is set (indicating an error), jump to the error handler.

pass:                   ; If the disk read was successful (carry flag is cleared), continue from here.
    jmp 0x0000:0x8000   ; Jump to the loaded Stage 2 at address 0x0000:0x8000 (this is where Stage 2 resides).
                        ; Here, 0x0000 is the segment, and 0x8000 is the offset.
                        ; Physical address = 0x0000 * 16 + 0x8000 = 0x8000, where Stage 2 is loaded.

disk_read_error:
    int 18h             ; If the disk read fails, call INT 18h to attempt a boot from a different device (like network boot).
                        ; This error message will occur --> IO write(0x01f0): current command is 20h displayed on bochs emulator.

TIMES 510-($-$$) DB 0   ; Pad the bootloader to ensure it is exactly 512 bytes, with zeros filling the remaining space.
DW 0xAA55               ; The boot signature (magic number) required for the BIOS to recognize this as a bootable sector.

stage2.asm:
[BITS 16]
[org 0x8000]

TSS_ADDR_HI_BYTE_OFFSET equ 5
TSS_ACCESS_BYTE_OFFSET  equ 7

jmp a20_enable

; -------------------------
; BSS Section for TSS
; -------------------------
section .bss
tss resb 104    ; Reserve 104 bytes for the TSS (Task State Segment)

; -------------------------
; Initialize the TSS
; -------------------------
section .text
 
init_tss:
    ; Set ESP0 (stack pointer for privilege level 0)
    mov eax, 0x9FC00        ; Example stack pointer for ring 0
    mov [tss + 4], eax      ; Set ESP0 in the TSS
 
    ; Set SS0 (stack segment for privilege level 0)
    mov ax, 0x10            ; Kernel data segment selector (0x10)
    mov [tss + 8], ax       ; Set SS0 in the TSS
 
    ; Swap the byte with tss address bits 24:31 with the access byte
    ; In the TSS descriptor
    mov al, [gdt.tss + TSS_ADDR_HI_BYTE_OFFSET]
    xchg al, [gdt.tss + TSS_ACCESS_BYTE_OFFSET]
    mov [gdt.tss + TSS_ADDR_HI_BYTE_OFFSET], al
 
    ret                     ; Return to the main flow

; -------------------------
; A20 Enable
; -------------------------
a20_enable:
    pushf               ; Save flags
    push ds             ; Save data segment
    push es             ; Save extra segment
    push di             ; Save destination index
    push si             ; Save source index

    cli

    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al

; -------------------------
; A20 Enable Msg
; -------------------------
status_a20_on:
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov ah, 0x0E         ; Set up for character output
    mov bh, 0x00         ; Display page number

    mov si, msg_a20_enable ; Load success message into SI

print_enable_loop:
    lodsb                ; Load next byte from message
    cmp al, 0            ; Check for null terminator
    je restore_registers_a20 ; If end of string, restore registers
    int 0x10             ; Print character in AL
    jmp print_enable_loop ; Loop to print the next character

restore_registers_a20:
    pop si               ; Restore source index
    pop di               ; Restore destination index
    pop es               ; Restore extra segment
    pop ds               ; Restore data segment
    popf                 ; Restore flags
 
    sti                  ; Re-enable interrupts


; -------------------------
; Load kernel from disk
; -------------------------
    mov ah, 02h         ; BIOS Interrupt 13h, Function 02h: Read sectors from the disk.
    mov al, 0Ah         ; Read 1 sector from the disk (this corresponds to the size of a sector, which is 512 bytes).

    mov ch, 00h         ; Set Cylinder number to 0 (since both Stage 1 and Stage 2 are on Cylinder 0).
    mov cl, 02h         ; Set Sector number to 2 (Stage 1 is in Sector 1, so Stage 2 starts at Sector 2).
    mov dh, 00h         ; Set Head number to 0 (assuming we are using Head 0 for now).
    mov dl, 80h         ; Use the first hard drive (usually 0x80 for the primary hard disk).

    mov ax, 0x1000      ; Load 0x1000 (segment for 1MB) into AX
    mov es, ax          ; Move AX (0x1000) into ES
    mov bx, 0x0000      ; Offset within the segment

    int 13h

    jmp gdt_setup

; -------------------------
; GDT Setup and TSS Setup
; -------------------------
gdt_setup:
    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; Load GDT descriptor into GDTR

    push ds
    push es
 
    call init_tss         ; Initialize the TSS
 
    pop es
    pop ds

; -------------------------
; GDT & TSS Success Message
; -------------------------
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov ah, 0x0E         ; Set up for character output
    mov bh, 0x00         ; Display page number

    mov si, msg_gdtss_success ; Load GDT success message into SI

gdtss_print_success:
    lodsb                   ; Load next byte from message
    cmp al, 0               ; Check for null terminator
    je enter_protected_mode     ; If end of string, proceed to protected mode
    int 0x10                ; Print character in AL
    jmp gdtss_print_success   ; Loop to print the next character

; -------------------------
; Enter Protected Mode
; -------------------------
enter_protected_mode:
    cli                 ; Disable interrupts before entering protected mode

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1           ; Set protected mode bit in CR0
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp 0x08:update_segments
; -------------------------
; Protected Mode Code Segment
; -------------------------
[BITS 32]
update_segments:
    cli
    
    mov ax, 0x10        ; Load GDT data segment selector (0x10)
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    mov ax, 0x28          ; TSS selector
    ltr ax                ; Load Task Register with TSS selector

; -------------------------
; Kernel Code
; -------------------------
kernel:
    jmp 0x08:0x100000

; -------------------------
; GDT Descriptor and TSS
; -------------------------
section .data
gdt_start:
gdt:
     ; Null Descriptor
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0
 
    ; Kernel Code Segment (DPL = 0)
    dw 0xFFFF              ; Limit
    dw 0x0000              ; Base (lower 16 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (next 8 bits)
    db 10011010b           ; Access byte
    db 11001111b           ; Flags and limit (upper 4 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (upper 8 bits)
 
    ; Kernel Data Segment (DPL = 0)
    dw 0xFFFF              ; Limit
    dw 0x0000              ; Base (lower 16 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (next 8 bits)
    db 10010010b           ; Access byte
    db 11001111b           ; Flags and limit (upper 4 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (upper 8 bits)
 
    ; User Code Segment (DPL = 3)
    dw 0xFFFF              ; Limit
    dw 0x0000              ; Base (lower 16 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (next 8 bits)
    db 11111010b           ; Access byte (DPL = 3)
    db 11001111b           ; Flags and limit (upper 4 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (upper 8 bits)
 
    ; User Data Segment (DPL = 3)
    dw 0xFFFF              ; Limit
    dw 0x0000              ; Base (lower 16 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (next 8 bits)
    db 11110010b           ; Access byte (DPL = 3)
    db 11001111b           ; Flags and limit (upper 4 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (upper 8 bits)
 
    ; TSS Descriptor
.tss:
    dw 0x0067                   ; Limit
    dd tss                      ; Base
    db 00000000b                ; Flags and limit (upper 4 bits)
    db 10001001b                ; Access byte
 
gdt_end:
 
; GDT Descriptor (contains size and location of GDT)
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1  ; Size of the GDT (in bytes, minus 1)
    dd gdt_start

; -------------------------
; Messages
; -------------------------
msg_a20_enable  db 'A20 line enable                 ->   successfully ', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0

msg_gdtss_success db 'GDT and TSS is configured       ->   successfully ', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0

kernel.c:
#define VIDEO_MEMORY 0xB8000
#define WHITE_ON_BLACK 0x0F
#define ROWS 25
#define COLS 80

void clear_screen() {
    volatile unsigned short *video = (unsigned short *) VIDEO_MEMORY;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS * COLS; i++) {
        video[i] = ' ' | (WHITE_ON_BLACK << 8);
    }
}

void print_string(const char *message) {
    volatile unsigned short *video = (unsigned short *) VIDEO_MEMORY;
    while (*message != '\0') {
        *video++ = (*message++) | (WHITE_ON_BLACK << 8);
    }
}

void _start(void) {
    clear_screen();
    print_string("Hello, Kernel World!");
    while(1);
}

Makefile:
PROJECT_ROOT := $(CURDIR)

STAGE1_SRC := $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Boot/Stage1/stage1.asm
STAGE2_SRC := $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Boot/Stage2/stage2.asm
KERNEL_SRC := $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Kernel/kernel.c
LINKER_SCRIPT := $(PROJECT_ROOT)/linker.ld

STAGE1_BIN := $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Boot/Stage1/stage1.bin
STAGE2_BIN := $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Boot/Stage2/stage2.bin
KERNEL_BIN := $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Kernel/kernel.bin

IMG := $(PROJECT_ROOT)/bootloader.img

QEMU_IMG := qemu-img
DD := dd

# Always clean before building
output: clean $(STAGE1_BIN) $(STAGE2_BIN) $(KERNEL_BIN) $(IMG)

$(STAGE1_BIN): $(STAGE1_SRC)
    @echo "Assembling Stage 1..."
    nasm -f bin "$(STAGE1_SRC)" -o "$(STAGE1_BIN)"

$(STAGE2_BIN): $(STAGE2_SRC)
    @echo "Assembling Stage 2..."
    nasm -f bin "$(STAGE2_SRC)" -o "$(STAGE2_BIN)"

$(KERNEL_BIN): $(KERNEL_SRC) $(LINKER_SCRIPT)
    @echo "Compiling and linking Kernel..."
    i686-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -c "$(KERNEL_SRC)" -o "$(PROJECT_ROOT)/Kernel/kernel.o"
    i686-elf-ld -o $(KERNEL_BIN) -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(PROJECT_ROOT)/Kernel/kernel.o

$(IMG): $(STAGE1_BIN) $(STAGE2_BIN) $(KERNEL_BIN)
    @echo "Creating bootloader.img..."
    $(QEMU_IMG) create -f raw "$(IMG)" 10M
    $(DD) if=$(STAGE1_BIN) of=$(IMG) bs=512 count=1
    $(DD) if=$(STAGE2_BIN) of=$(IMG) bs=512 seek=1
    $(DD) if=$(KERNEL_BIN) of=$(IMG) bs=512 seek=2

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up..."
    rm -f "$(STAGE1_BIN)" "$(STAGE2_BIN)" "$(KERNEL_BIN)" "$(IMG)" "$(PROJECT_ROOT)/Kernel/kernel.o"

linker.ld:
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x100000;
    
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }

    .rodata : {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}

Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    build-essential \
    libtool \
    pkg-config \
    nasm \
    qemu-system-x86 \
    gcc \
    gdb \
    make \
    bison \
    flex \
    libgmp3-dev \
    libmpc-dev \
    libmpfr-dev \
    texinfo \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download and build the i686-elf cross-compiler
RUN mkdir /usr/local/cross && cd /usr/local/cross && \
    wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.36.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf binutils-2.36.tar.gz && \
    cd binutils-2.36 && \
    mkdir build && cd build && \
    ../configure --target=i686-elf --prefix=/usr/local/cross --disable-nls --disable-werror && \
    make && make install && \
    cd ../../ && \
    wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-10.2.0/gcc-10.2.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf gcc-10.2.0.tar.gz && \
    cd gcc-10.2.0 && \
    mkdir build && cd build && \
    ../configure --target=i686-elf --prefix=/usr/local/cross --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers && \
    make all-gcc && make all-target-libgcc && \
    make install-gcc && make install-target-libgcc

# Set environment variables for cross-compilation
ENV PATH="/usr/local/cross/bin:$PATH"

# Set the working directory for the bootloader project
WORKDIR /usr/src/bootloader

# Copy all files from the current directory to the Docker container
COPY . /usr/src/bootloader

# Compile and run the bootloader and kernel
CMD ["sh", "-c", "make clean && make output && qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=bootloader.img -nographic -serial mon:stdio"]

I expected the kernel to be loaded at 0x100000 and to print "Hello, Kernel World!" to the screen once it executes. However, when inspecting memory using the QEMU monitor (xp /16x 0x100000), the memory at 0x100000 is all zeros, indicating the kernel wasn't loaded.
Here is what I have tried so far:

I confirmed that my bootloader reads from the disk using BIOS interrupt int 13h.

I checked that the kernel.bin is compiled and linked to start at 0x100000.

I verified the number of sectors the bootloader reads matches the size of the kernel.

I inspected the disk image using a hex editor to ensure the kernel is written to the correct location (sector 2 onwards).


Despite these efforts, the kernel is still not appearing in memory.

You're loading your kernel at address 0x10000( 0x1000:0x0000), not 0x100000.  That's the segment for 64 KB, not 1 MB.  The 16-bit BIOS can't access 0x100000 as it is outside the first megabyte of memory.  If you want your kernel there, you'll have to load the sectors somewhere else and copy them after entering protected mode.

Also, it looks as though your kernel is being linked as an ELF executable, not a raw binary.

I guess if A20 is enabled, it may work to have the BIOS load your kernel at linear address 0x100000, provided it's less than 64K or so, but you'll have to pass a seg:ofs address like 0xffff:0x0010.

So, I can't use INT 13? to load in 1MB?

and yes I use linker to link all .c files but what do you mean "not a raw binary." ??

cause I did compiling and linking and got .BIN file

"So, I can't use INT 13? to load in 1MB?" That's correct.  INT 13 is a PC BIOS interface.  It works only in real mode, where you effectively have an 8086 CPU from the late 1970s and can only access the low 1 MB.

You named it .bin, but it's actually going to be an ELF binary, with ELF headers and all, unless I am missing something.  If you look at the first few bytes, they will likely be the ELF header, rather than the first instructions of your kernel.  You need --oformat=binary on your ld command line, or an OUTPUT_FORMAT command in your linker script.

@NateEldredge: I recommend using LD (or GCC) to generate the ELF executable (output it to a file called kernel.elf in this case). Then use i686-elf-objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin . This has the advantage of having both files. The ELF file can be used for debug information (when using GDB with QEMU) and the binary runs in the emulator from a disk image. I recommend using objcopy as well since the binary output from LD using --oformat=binary can generate unexpected output in certain scenarios.

The best way (using legacy BIOS) to load a kernel to 0x100000 (and higher) using your own bootloader is to read the kernel in chunks in memory below 0x100000 using Int 0x13; switch into 32-bit protected mode; copy the chunk to the area >= 0x100000; return to real mode; repeat until the entire kernel has been processed. If your kernel is small enough to be entirely read into the memory below 1MiB then you can read the whole thing; switch into 32-bit protected mode; copy the kernel  0x100000) and the jump to the code at 0x100000.

I got it, Thanks Man!

Here are all the changes I’ve added: https://github.com/IlanVinograd/OS_32Bit

But do I understand correctly that the maximum number of bytes that BIOS INT 13h can read with your trick would be:
0xFFFF0−0x10000=1,048,576−65,536=983,024 bytes?
Thus,  load kernel cannot read larger than this size?

Which trick are you referring to?

you provide me code where you load kernel by int 13,in lines 90-106 and then you copy the kernel above 1MB, kernel copy (the trick) lines 174 - 184

Okay, although low memory is 1MiB in size, not all of it is usable. Basically consider everything above 0xA0000 as part of the BIOS or memory mapped IO (BIOS, text mode, graphics mode buffers etc). There is also a part of the memory just below 0xA0000 that is unusable. IT is called the EBDA. On most systems it is 1KiB in size (it can be more). You can find the EBDA size in kilobytes by reading memory address 0x0413. On a system with a KiB EBDA memory would be usable up to 0xA0000-1024=0x9FC00. 0x9FC00 minus the start address of 0x10000 = 0x8FC00 = 588,800 bytes.

You could extend the size of the kernel a bit more by reading stage 2 to 0x7e00 and the kernel to 0x08000 giving you an additional 32768 bytes. For that to work you'd have to move your real mode stack from 0xFFFE (that you currently use) to somewhere safer where you won't read data on top of it. (Using 0x7c00 instead would be out of the way below the bootloader)

If you want to know more about the EBDA area below 0xA0000 see this info: https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)#Extended_BIOS_Data_Area_(EBDA)

Good to know, basically I have approximately  588,800 bytes for any use, like load kernel or any other things.
